# Google AppEngine BlobInfo() features

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstorage

### Hi!

The [official GAE documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/ru/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobinfoclass.html) instists on existing such heplful BlobInfo instance properties as:

- content_type;
- creation;
- filename;
- size

I have try to using them in my app, but I'm can't imagine how to do it correctly and I'm can't find a some practical examples how to utilize this GAE features nowhere. Can you help me by demonstation a scratches of verified python code?

### Real thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do? The docs include examples of uploading to the blobstore; if there's something in particular that you want to do with it that isn't documented here, tell us specifically and perhaps we can help.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you have the key to your blob in a variable named blob_key.  You could write code like this:

```
blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key)
print('filename: %s' % blob_info.filename)
```

blob key is usually returned by the BlobstoreUploadHandler that you use to upload your file.